# Swift 3 check internet connection with Reachability

Tags: ios, swift, reachability, reachability-swift

so I'm looking at using this GitHub api to that checks for the reachability of a host.: https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift/tree/feature/ios10

however its pretty bare bones and I'm getting a few errors when trying to write a function that will use this code. I'm calling it from viewdidload

```
setupReachability(hostName: nil)

var reachability:Reachability?

var connected = false

func setupReachability (hostName:String?) {
    do {
        let reachability = try hostName == nil ? Reachability() : Reachability(hostname: hostName!)
        self.reachability = reachability

        try! self.reachability?.startNotifier()
    } catch ReachabilityError.FailedToCreateWithAddress(let address) {
        print(address)
        return
    } catch {}
    //now that the reacability function is created set a notification
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: "reachabilityChanged", name: ReachabilityChangedNotification, object: reachability)

}

func reachabilityChanged(notification: Notification) {
    let reachability = notification.object as! Reachability

    if reachability.isReachable {
        if reachability.isReachableViaWiFi {
            connected = true
            print("Connected via WiFi")
        } else {
            connected = true
            print("Connected via Cellular")
        }
    } else {
        connected = false
        print("Not Connected")
    }
}
```

this is my error log:

```
2016-12-28 08:53:25.441 ParseStarterProject-Swift[92944:1919466] Simulator user has requested new graphics quality: 100
2016-12-28 08:53:29.697 ParseStarterProject-Swift[92944:1919546] -[ParseStarterProject_Swift.PackViewController reachabilityChanged]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fafabd0bb40
2016-12-28 08:53:29.712 ParseStarterProject-Swift[92944:1919546] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ParseStarterProject_Swift.PackViewController reachabilityChanged]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fafabd0bb40'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ad98d4b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010a7fa21e objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ae08f04 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ad1e005 ___forwarding___ + 1013
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ad1db88 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ad365ec __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 12
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ad364eb _CFXRegistrationPost + 427
    7   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ad36252 ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke + 50
    8   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010acf9282 -[_CFXNotificationRegistrar find:object:observer:enumerator:] + 2018
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010acf831b _CFXNotificationPost + 667
    10  Foundation                          0x000000010a2c081b -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 66
    11  ParseStarterProject-Swift           0x000000010983fabe _TFC25ParseStarterProject_Swift12ReachabilityP33_3EC4A4DB94B171724E68742C2AA9888E19reachabilityChangedfT_T_ + 462
    12  ParseStarterProject-Swift           0x0000000109841205 _TFFC25ParseStarterProject_Swift12Reachability13startNotifierFzT_T_U_FT_T_ + 21
    13  ParseStarterProject-Swift           0x0000000109811f17 _TTRXFo___XFdCb___ + 39
    14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010df1b978 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010df450cd _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010df22e17 _dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 236
    17  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010df23b4b _dispatch_queue_invoke + 1073
    18  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010df2402b _dispatch_queue_override_invoke + 683
    19  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010df26385 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 720
    20  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010df26059 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 123
    21  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010e39f712 _pthread_wqthread + 1299
    22  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010e39f1ed start_wqthread + 13
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

EDIT

[image]

Comment: Did you try Apple's popular example of Reachability before attempting to use other third parties? [`pod 'AppleReachability'`](https://cocoapods.org/pods/AppleReachability)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot a colon on the `reachabilityChanged:` selector. You need it to indicate that an argument is to be passed:

`NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: "reachabilityChanged:", name: ReachabilityChangedNotification, object: reachability)`

Comment: Ive edited my question.  It got past that error, now it prompts for keychain and crashes